# Matlab, barchart and legends

Tags: matlab

I have a function `plot_result()`which plots bars from the result on the basis of a test. I have two vectors:

```
R = [0 1 1 -1] containing logical true or false from the questions. and
T = [0 1 2 3] containing time spent on each questions.

0 - in R means a question not answered
```

a bar is green if the answer is 1 and red otherwise. 
But the legends show something else than expected.

in the above case R and T the 
legend show:

```
Green - "Right answer"
Green - "Right answer"
```

instead of

```
Green - "Right answer"
Red   - "Wrong answer"
```

sometimes it also shows 3 legends instead of two - what am I doing wrong ?

```
R = [0 1 1 -1];
T = [0 1 2 3];


if sum(T) ~= 0 

% Barchart
figure;
for i=1:length(T)
    h(i) = bar(i, T(i));
       if i == 1 hold on, end
          if R(i) == -1 
             col = 'r';
             legendInfo{i} = ['Wrong Answer '];
          else
             col = 'g';
             legendInfo{i} = ['Right Answer '];
          end

       set(h(i), 'FaceColor', col)
       end
   end

         set(gca,'xTick',1:length(R),'xTickLabel',1:length(R))
         xlabel('Answer No..');
         ylabel('Time per. question')
         title('Question vs. time')
         set(gca,'YLim',[0 max(T)])

         [~,legendsIWant]=unique(nonzeros(R)); 
         legend(h(legendsIWant),legendInfo(legendsIWant),'Location', 'BestOutside'   'FontSize', 8);
```

Comment: Do you have a set of inputs which generate 3 legend entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the given input is `[~,legendsIWant]=unique(nonzeros(R))` will give the indexes values corresponding to nonzeros(R) not R

a possible fix would be to get all unique values locations and then discard any corresponding to zero
e.g. replace the line mentioned with

```
[uniqueValues,legendsIWant]=unique(R)
legendsIWant=legendsIWant(uniqueValues~=0)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I had completely missed that the line returned indexes and not the values ​​themselves. Thanks you.

Comment: no problem, I'm still unsure how 3 entries could have been created, this may not address that issue, if you have a set of inputs which cause 3 entries I would be interested to see it!

Comment: for some reason I can't come up with the 3 legends, it was probably just a one-off.